# Unit testing with I/O dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, rhino-mocks

I would like to test the following class but I/O and sealed class dependencies are making it quite hard.

```
public class ImageDrawingCombiner
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Save image to a specified location in path
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Location to save the image</param>
    /// <param name="surface">The image as canvas</param>
    public void CombineDrawingsIntoImage(Uri path, Canvas surface)
    {
        Size size = new Size(surface.ActualWidth, surface.ActualHeight);

        // Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
        RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderBitmap.Render(surface);

        SaveBitmapAsPngImage(path, renderBitmap);
    }

    // SaveBitmapAsPngImage(path, renderBitmap);
    private void SaveBitmapAsPngImage(Uri path, RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap)
    {
        // Create a file stream for saving image
        using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(path.LocalPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            // Use png encoder for our data
            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            // push the rendered bitmap to it
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
            // save the data to the stream
            encoder.Save(outStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Refactored the SaveBitmapAsPngImage method a bit:

```
// SaveBitmapAsPngImage(path, renderBitmap, new PngBitmapEncoder());
    public void SaveBitmapAsPngImage(Uri path, BitmapSource renderBitmap, BitmapEncoder pngBitmapEncoder)
    {
        // Create a file stream for saving image
        using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(path.LocalPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            // Use png encoder for our data
            // push the rendered bitmap to it
            pngBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
            // save the data to the stream
            pngBitmapEncoder.Save(outStream);

}
```

Made it public to be testable (code smell?). It is still using FileStream. Some would suggest to replace it with MemoryStream and/or Factory pattern but in the end it has be to saved to the image file somewhere.

Even if I replace all the I/O based calls with wrappers or interfaces (SystemInterface):
 - Where should the instances be initialised? At the composite root? That is a lot to bubble up...
 - How would I avoid the "up to 3 constructor parameter" rule with DI?
 - It all sounds a lot of work for this simple function

The test(s) should make sure the image file is produces.

EDIT:
Tried to run the @Nkosi Moq test but it needed a repair. Replaced:

```
var renderBitmap = new Canvas();
```

with:

```
Size renderSize = new Size(100, 50);
var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)renderSize.Width, (int)renderSize.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
```

Test result:

> BitmapServiceTest.BitmapService_Should_SaveBitmapAsPngImage threw
>   exception:  System.IO.IOException: Cannot read from the stream. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x88982F72
>       at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.Save(Stream stream)

Seems like the encoder is not happy with the mocked Moq stream. Should the PngBitmapEncoder dependency also by method injected (and mocked in tests)?

Comment: The class saves an image to a file on the disk. It seems like that's basically all it does. So if you want to verify the functionality of this class you should verify that there actually is a file on disk after you have called the CombineDrawingsIntoImage method. If you mock out this functionality there is not much to be tested, is it?

Comment: Test your private methods by calling your public methods. If that becomes unwieldy, there is a very good chance that your class is doing too much and that SaveBitmapAsPngImage belongs on another class (which can be separately tested).

Comment: @mm8 Integration test with file checking make sense. In this case the unit testable class helps me to verify of separation of conserns and design it the S.O.L.I.D principles in mind.

Comment: @adam-g Currently it is not possible to unit test the public method as it is because of the dependencies. Therefore I would like to learn what would be the perfect or optimal design.

Comment: Below @Nkosi showed one solution. Is it perfect?

Comment: Perfect is a very strong compliment. It is very good. Read the bit in brackets in their first paragraph until it sinks in. Your class doesn't need to know how to SaveBitmapAsPngImage. It just needs access to something that it can ask to do that (the IBitmapService in the example). You can then use Moq (or your favourite mocking framework) to inject a fake one for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all a matter of design. Try to avoid tight coupling to implementation concerns (classes should depend on abstractions and not on concretions).

Consider the following based on your current design

```
public interface IBitmapService {
    void SaveBitmapAsPngImage(Uri path, BitmapSource renderBitmap);
}

public interface IFileSystem {
    Stream OpenOrCreateFileStream(string path);
}

public class PhysicalFileSystem : IFileSystem {
    public Stream OpenOrCreateFileStream(string path) {
        return new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    }
}

public class BitmapService : IBitmapService {
    private readonly IFileSystem fileSystem;

    public BitmapService(IFileSystem fileSystem) {
        this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }

    // SaveBitmapAsPngImage(path, renderBitmap);
    public void SaveBitmapAsPngImage(Uri path, BitmapSource renderBitmap) {
        // Create a file stream for saving image
        using (var outStream = fileSystem.OpenOrCreateFileStream(path.LocalPath)) {
            // Use png encoder for our data
            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            // push the rendered bitmap to it
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
            // save the data to the stream
            encoder.Save(outStream);
        }
    }
}

public interface IImageDrawingCombiner {
    void CombineDrawingsIntoImage(Uri path, Canvas surface);
}

public class ImageDrawingCombiner : IImageDrawingCombiner {
    private readonly IBitmapService service;

    public ImageDrawingCombiner(IBitmapService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Save image to a specified location in path
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Location to save the image</param>
    /// <param name="surface">The image as canvas</param>
    public void CombineDrawingsIntoImage(Uri path, Canvas surface) {
        var size = new Size(surface.ActualWidth, surface.ActualHeight);
        // Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
        var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderBitmap.Render(surface);
        service.SaveBitmapAsPngImage(path, renderBitmap);
    }
}
```

`FileStream` is an implementation concern that can be abstracted out when unit testing in isolation.

Every implementation above can be tested on its own in isolation with their dependencies capable of being mocked and injected as needed. In production, dependencies can be be added in the composition root with a DI container.

> How to assert that `encoder.Save(outStream)` is called?

Given that you control the creation of the stream and that `System.IO.Stream` is abstract you can easily mock it and verify that it was written to as the `encode.Save` would have to write to the stream while performing its functions.

Here is a simple example using `Moq` mocking framework targeting the refactored code in the previous example.

```
[TestClass]
public class BitmapServiceTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void BitmapService_Should_SaveBitmapAsPngImage() {
        //Arrange
        var mockedStream = Mock.Of<Stream>(_ => _.CanRead == true && _.CanWrite == true);
        Mock.Get(mockedStream).SetupAllProperties();
        var fileSystemMock = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
        fileSystemMock
            .Setup(_ => _.OpenOrCreateFileStream(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(mockedStream);

        var sut = new BitmapService(fileSystemMock.Object);
        var renderBitmap = new Canvas();
        var path = new Uri("//A_valid_path");

        //Act
        sut.SaveBitmapAsPngImage(path, renderBitmap);

        //Assert
        Mock.Get(mockedStream).Verify(_ => _.Write(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
    }
}
```

A commentor suggested using a memory stream, which I would suggest in most other scenarios, but in this case the stream is being disposed within the method under test as it is wrapped in a `using` statement. This would make calling members on the stream after being disposed to throw exceptions. By mocking the stream outright you have more control of asserting what was called.

Comment: How would you arrange the interfaces and service (project/directory) in the VS solution in this case? For example, I have a WPF.Main (MVVM), Logic and Logic.Interfaces projects. Shouldn't the PngBitmapEncoder? How to assert that encoder.Save(outStream) is called? Much appreciated!

Comment: You can implement a mock IFileSystem that returned a memorystream instead of a FileStream. You can then check the contents of that memory stream. Alternatively, you may be able to extract an interface as an IPngBitmapEncoder and using a DI container, inject a mock one in your test and the real one in production.

Comment: Having difficultis with Rhino Stream stub: "encoder.Save(outStream);" System.IO.IOException : Cannot read from the stream. Does the Moq test really work?

Comment: @JPollack yes. Tested it and passes. I used a few replacements for some of the objects and then adjusted it to suit this particular scenario as a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: For me the test fails. See details in my edited question.

Comment: @JPollack  Ok, try this approach. create a class that inherits from `MemoryStream`. Override the `Dispose` method to do nothing so you don't lose the stream when making your assertions. I prefer the mock approach but what I just suggested also works.

Comment: I also prefer the mock approach if it would work or at least Stub which should act similar to a Stream wrapper...